# tab is not loading when I click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Here is my code I pulled out from the internet which works fine in Online Snippets but when I copy and run it on my local computer , the tab stays same. Please help me

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
$(".btn-pref .btn").click(function () {
    $(".btn-pref .btn").removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-default");
    // $(".tab").addClass("active"); // instead of this do the below 
    $(this).removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-primary");   
});
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="card hovercard">
       
    <div class="btn-pref btn-group btn-group-justified btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" id="stars" class="btn btn-primary" href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <div class="hidden-xs">Stars</div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" id="favorites" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <div class="hidden-xs">Favorites</div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" id="following" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <div class="hidden-xs">Following</div>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="well">
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1">
          <h3>This is tab 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="tab2">
          <h3>This is tab 2</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="tab3">
          <h3>This is tab 3</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    </div>
            
    </div>
```

I would be very greatful, If anyone could help me what I am doing wrong. For reference, here is the original link to above bootstrap theme.
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/people-card-with-tabs

Comment: Are you loading only the Bootstrap's CSS? The tabs are working if bootstrap.js is also loaded.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette, I don't understand what do you mean by that. But yes if I'm not wrong, yes I'm only loading Bootstrap's Css and Jquery library.

Comment: Bootstrap is a JS library... You have to load it. [Look here for the CDN](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you didn't include the `bootstrap.min.js` file, you only included the jQuery and the `bootstrap.min.css` file.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
$(".btn-pref .btn").click(function () {
    $(".btn-pref .btn").removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-default");
    // $(".tab").addClass("active"); // instead of this do the below 
    $(this).removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-primary");   
});
});
```

```html
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="card hovercard">
       
    <div class="btn-pref btn-group btn-group-justified btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" id="stars" class="btn btn-primary" href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <div class="hidden-xs">Stars</div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" id="favorites" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <div class="hidden-xs">Favorites</div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" id="following" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <div class="hidden-xs">Following</div>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="well">
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1">
          <h3>This is tab 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="tab2">
          <h3>This is tab 2</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="tab3">
          <h3>This is tab 3</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    </div>
            
    </div>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

---

## My 2 cents:

You should try and be more careful.
You should try and debug the problem, starting always from the most obvious reasons first.

Comment: Thanks, I was scratching my head around. Thank you for your great support.

Comment: No problem. If you found my answer useful, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to load your js at the end of the body.

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="card hovercard">

        <div class="btn-pref btn-group btn-group-justified btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <button type="button" id="stars" class="btn btn-primary" href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <div class="hidden-xs">Stars</div>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <button type="button" id="favorites" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <div class="hidden-xs">Favorites</div>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <button type="button" id="following" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <div class="hidden-xs">Following</div>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="well">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1">
                    <h3>This is tab 1</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="tab2">
                    <h3>This is tab 2</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="tab3">
                    <h3>This is tab 3</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".btn-pref .btn").click(function () {
            $(".btn-pref .btn").removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-default");
            // $(".tab").addClass("active"); // instead of this do the below 
            $(this).removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-primary");
        });
    });
</script>
```